# C++ Long arithmetic

Tags: c++

The program reads `2` variables a and b and displays their sum. The size of the numbers can go up to `10^100`.

Program almost works. When we add `11` and `11`, outputs correctly `22`. But for example when `15` and `15`, instead of `30` displays `20`.

What is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str1, str2;

    cin>>str1>>str2;

    int len1 = str1.length();
    int len2 = str2.length();

    char mas1[101], mas2[101];
    int mas3[101], mas4[101];

    for(int i=0; i<len1; i++)
    {
        strcpy(mas1, str1.c_str());
        int ia = mas1[i] - '0';
        mas3[i] = ia;
    }

    for(int i=0; i< len2; i++)
    {
        strcpy(mas2, str2.c_str()); 
        int ia = mas2[i] - '0';
         mas4[i] = ia;
    }

    int length;
    if (len1 > len2)
           length = len1 + 1;
    else
       length = len2 + 1;

    for (int ix = 0; ix < length; ix++)
    {
         mas4[ix] += mas3[ix];
         mas4[ix + 1] += (mas4[ix] / 10);
         mas4[ix] %= 10; 
    }

    if (mas4[length - 1] == 0)
       length--;

    for(int i=0;i<len2;i++)
    {
        cout<<mas4[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Your code would be easier to read and debug if it had some explanatory comments in it.

Answer (score 1):

You add integers to your array in the same order they appear in the string:

```
for(int i=0;i<len1;i++) {
    strcpy(mas1, str1.c_str());
    int ia = mas1[i] - '0';
    mas3[i] = ia;
}

for(int i=0;i<len2;i++) {
    strcpy(mas2, str2.c_str()); 
    int ia = mas2[i] - '0';
    mas4[i] = ia;
}
```

And then you add up the digits in the same order, from low index to high index:

```
for (int ix = 0; ix < length; ix++) {
    mas4[ix] += mas3[ix];
    mas4[ix + 1] += (mas4[ix] / 10);
    mas4[ix] %= 10; 
}
```

So you are basically adding up the tens, then the ones, and are incorrectly carrying from the tens into the ones.  If you think about how you add two numbers on paper, you will see this is not correct.  You need to start with the ones, and carry to the tens, and so on.  So either reverse the order you save the integers in your array, or reverse the order in which you add them, being careful if you need to create a new digit place due to carry from the largest digit.